# How do I setup an assets feed using the FeedMe plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-feedme

I want to setup an assets feed using the `FeedMe` plug-in.  Everything is well documented, but the documentation for assets is still TBA.

I previously created and updated entries using `FeedMe`.  Now, I want to add a PDF asset to each entry.

My PDFs are already uploaded to an S3 bucket assigned to the asset field I want to `FeedMe` to update.  But, I can take them down and start clean if that works best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they've added the documentation you're wanting here: https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/content-mapping/field-types#assets

> ## Assets
>
> Accepts single or multiple values. You should supply the filename only, excluding the full path to the asset, but including the filename. If you're uploading remote assets, you'll need to produce fully-qualified URLs.
>
> #### Additional Options
>
> - Upload remote asset (choose how to handle existing assets - Replace/Keep/Ignore)
> - Inner-element fields

```
<Asset>my_filename.jpg</Asset>
// Or
<Assets>
    <Asset>my_filename.jpg</Asset>
    <Asset>my_other_filename.jpg</Asset>
</Assets>

//
// When selecting upload
//
<Asset>http://mydomain.com/my_filename.jpg</Asset>

// Or
<Assets>
    <Asset>http://mydomain.com/my_filename.jpg</Asset>
    <Asset>http://mydomain.com/my_other_filename.jpg</Asset>
</Assets>
```